# How to load functions.php in theme from external URL

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

We have this serious issue in WordPress. We have this problem that clients download all the files from the server and uploads it to his. Now we want to do this.

1. Host the functions.php on our server. The entire code. Lets call this file (FILE A) an it is on ABC.com
2. In the themes folder's function.php file ( FILE B) , we want the FILE A to be rendered .

We tried to directly include FILE A into FILE B, but it is not possible as many servers dont allow this to happen.

Now we want a mechanism where in if someone downloads the files from our server without out permission, then we just comment the code in FILE A and the website becomes disfunctional.

Can anyone give me a way to do this?

A way to load the external file's code into theme's functions.php

I will really be obliged

Thanks in advance

Comment: Many servers don't allow include? o.O Why wouldn't they? I guess if they don't allow it then the only way would be to paste the whole file A in file B, instead of including it.